# spyder- anaconda stop working suddenly after installing ax-platform lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

i working in spyder for long time, but after i install ax-platform lib it stop working and out this error massage 
i tried to uninstall it from anaconda then reinstall it again but the same error appeared
could any help me how to fix it

the error massage as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3734, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3590, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 977, in setup
'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\__init__.py", line 14, in 
from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\plugin.py", line 29, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\confpage.py", line 16, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\widgets\pylintgui.py", line 37, in 
from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\utils.py", line 16, in 
import pylint.config
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\config.py", line 54, in 
import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something probably changed in dependencies, this solved the issue for me:

```
conda install toml
```